# How to embed shellinabox into my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ssh, console

I am trying to ssh into some machine , but port 22  is blocked due to 
our college firewall .

Later  I was able to ssh using web-ssh client : [shellinabox](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shellinabox/)  running in  some  server , but i don't have sudo access in that server, as I need to download some software too , I planned to install **shellinabox using iframe<>**
in my server , but i have no idea how to do it ??

I have no ssh-access to my server so I can't install it using apt-get

Can anyone help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing shellinabox you need a working server.

Access your shellinbox server from outside your LAN

Configure your home router to forward TCP traffic port 443 (assuming you followed the above tip) to your computer's IP address. You can right click on the Network Manager applet and choose connection information to find your computers IP address. Now you can access your computer when away from home by navigating to https://yourpublicIPaddress. You can get your public IP address by going to http://whatismyip.com. To make it easier to remember your public IP address you can register with a Dynamic DNS service.

If you wish to install shellinabox in your web page after installing a working server by using iframe use the below mentioned command

```
<iframe src="https://yourpublicIpaddress" width="300" height="300" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe>
```